# How to refresh div onclick in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jquery programming. I was curious if there is a way to refresh div on button click? I only know window.location.reload() method, but it refreshes my whole page.

```html
    <div id="container">
      <div id="content">
        <p style="border: 2px solid black">
          What's up?
        </p>
      </div>
      <button>Refresh DIV</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: By refresh you mean get rid of all it's content?

Comment: What do you mean by refreshing a div? Getting it back to the initial state?

Comment: What do you mean by refreshing ? changing text or something else. And please provide your jquery code that you worked on so far

Comment: Yeah, I  mean getting it back to the initial state

Comment: Why would it have changed? You've shown us no code that would change it so why would you need to get it back to it's initial state?

Comment: My project code is very confusing and long, so I though I'll give you a simple example of my idea. In my content div I have another button that changes color of border to red. So my idea is to make it black again by pressing button "Refresh DIV"

Comment: What is initial state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some example:

```js
var storeColor = 'red';

$('#container').on('click', 'button', function() {
  var $p = $('#content p');
  var tmp = $p.css('border-color');
  $p.css('border-color', storeColor);
  storeColor = tmp;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <p style="border: 2px solid black">
      What's up?
    </p>
  </div>
  <button type="button">Refresh DIV</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I probably shouldn't be answering as there's a real likelihood that the parameters will change and require changes to this answer. As is though, you can use `addClass()`, `removeClass()` or `toggleClass()` to easily add/remove styling such as a border or background color.

We have moved the default styling and the *"changed/active"* styling to CSS classes. Below we simply tell the the click handler to either add or remove the class that changes it from the default styling.

```js
var $btn0 = $( '.other' ),
    $btn1 = $( '.refresh-target' ),
    $target = $( '.target' );

$btn0.on( 'click', function ( e ) {
  $target.toggleClass( 'highlight', true );
} );

$btn1.on( 'click', function ( e ) {
  $target.toggleClass( 'highlight', false );
} );
```

```css
.target {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.highlight {
  border-color: indianred;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">

  <div id="content">
  
    <!-- OP mentioned another button in #content, so here's my interpretation of another button in #content. -->
    <button class="other">Turn Red</button>
  
    <p class="target">
      What's up?
    </p>
    
  </div>
  
  <button class="refresh-target">Refresh DIV</button>
  
</div>
```